# Why doesn't my form work on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have a form downloaded from http://reusableforms.com/ that works great on desktop. But the submit button changes to "sending ..." and gets stuck on mobile devices. An error message doesn't display and the page just stops working. What would cause this problem? I am putting my javascript code below. Here is the site for reference: http://jasminew.xyz/flash

```
$(function()
{

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // or iPhones don't get fresh data

function after_form_submitted(data) 
{
    if(data.result == 'success')
    {
        $('#carouselExampleIndicators').hide();
        $('form#reused_form').hide();
        $('#success_message').show();
        $('#error_message').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

        jQuery.each(data.errors,function(key,val)
        {
            $('#error_message 
ul').append('<li>'+key+':'+val+'</li>');
        });
        $('#success_message').hide();
        $('#error_message').show();

        //reverse the response on the button
        $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function()
        {
            $btn = $(this);
            label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
            if(label)
            {
                $btn.prop('type','submit' ); 
                $btn.text(label);
                $btn.prop('orig_label','');
            }
        });

    }//else
  }

$('#reused_form').submit(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);
    //show some response on the button
    $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function()
    {
        $btn = $(this);
        $btn.prop('type','button' ); 
        $btn.prop('orig_label',$btn.text());
        $btn.text('Sending ...');
    });


                var formdata = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'handler.php',
            data: formdata,
            success: after_form_submitted,
            dataType: 'json' ,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
        });

  });   
});
```

**EDIT**
I have opened remote Safari dev tools and the XHR Post is timing out. I'm not sure what that means.

**EDIT**
Okay, the problem is that the form stops working if the two upload fields in the form aren't used on iOS. Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: what shows in your browsers network panel? is there a request being made or not? anything in the console?

Comment: @delboy1978uk the form works fine when looking in my browser. I'm not sure how to open the console on Chrome's mobile browser on iOS.

Comment: you should be able to emulate mobile on your desktop browser. have you tried Firefox Developer Edition?

Comment: Works on Huawei P10light in Chrome Browser

Comment: @delboy1978uk it seems like it's just emulating how it would look on the mobile device, not how it functions.. I just downloaded Firefox Developer Edition and it also works fine while emulating an iPhone

Comment: @salsaverde if the submission of the form gets "stuck" after the button changes to "Sending..." text, this would suggest an issue in your AJAX. Please clarify your testing environment, are you using a mobile device on your wifi or carrier? iPhone or Android? Which browsers? It could be the creation of the form data or the ajax... hard to tell. But if you have mobile device on wifi, you could attempt to capture the traffic from your network, and should be able to identify the POST request and response from and to the device. This can help identify the issue without console on the device.

Comment: @Twisty I am testing this with my iPhone 7+ on both WiFi and carrier. The client that this is made for has also tested it with their iPhone and it isn't working. I've tried it on both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @Twisty I have opened remote Safari dev tools and the XHR Post is timing out. I'm not sure how to fix that or what that means.

Comment: This seems a really inefficient way to do ajax...

Comment: inefficient in what way?

Comment: @salsaverde the XHR Timeout means that the POST Request is unable to reach the destination or the PHP Script. Make sure your `url` path is correctly.

Comment: @salsaverde is 'handler.php' in the same folder on the server? May also try './handler.php' as an alternative relative path. The AJAX must be able to post to the PHP properly. Can also test by navigating to the handler.php on mobile directly.

Comment: @KevinB why create a new function when you can place it all in the success callback?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs i’d hardly call one more function inefficient. we’re talking about using jquery here after all. the pillar of efficiency!

Comment: @KevinB but why add more lines to the code? Just seems backwards to me haha and yeah I s'pose xD

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code and would suggest some minor updates:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  }); // or iPhones don't get fresh data

  function after_form_submitted(data) {
    if (data.result == 'success') {
      $('#carouselExampleIndicators').hide();
      $('form#reused_form').hide();
      $('#success_message').show();
      $('#error_message').hide();
    } else {
      $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');
      $.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {
        $("<li>").html(key + ": " + val).appendTo($('#error_message ul'));
      });
      $('#success_message').hide();
      $('#error_message').show();

      //reverse the response on the button
      $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function() {
        var $btn = $(this);
        var label = $btn.data('orig-label');
        if (label) {
          $btn.prop('type', 'submit');
          $btn.text(label);
          $btn.data('orig-label', null);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  $('#reused_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    //show some response on the button
    $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function() {
      var $btn = $(this);
      $btn.prop('type', 'button');
      $btn.data('orig-label', $btn.text());
      $btn.text('Sending ...');
    });

    var formdata = new FormData($form[0]);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'handler.php',
      data: formdata,
      success: after_form_submitted,
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
    });
  });
});
```

I see nothing that is "wrong", just some syntax cleanup. Also `this` was sort of ambiguous in the creation of FormData, so I switched to a more specific element: `$form[0]`.

I adjusted a few other things to be more jQuery like. All functions the same.

Also, make sure that Ajax URL path is correct. You have:

```
url: 'handler.php'
```

Make sure that your can browse to this directly. If the path is not correct, the form will not post properly. It may be better to use a Direct URL Path instead of a relative path.

If you have access to your Web Server or PHP Logs, you can also check there to see if POSTs to your handler.php script are failing in some way. In Safari, you may want to check Network results and see if it provide more response details.

Test it, let me know if it works any better.